# NodeJS: readdir() returns "undefined" instead of the list of files?

Tags: node.js, readdir

I'm trying to check how many files does have a directory using NodeJS's File System.

```
var fs =require('fs');

function listaArchivos(directorio){
    fs.readdir(directorio, function(err, archivos){
            if(!err) {
                console.log(archivos);
            } else {console.log(err)}
        })
}

var directorio = 'home/Rosamunda/Desktop/coderhouse/fs/';
listaArchivos(directorio);
```

I receive this error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, readdir 'home/Rosamunda/Desktop/coderhouse/fs/']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'home/Rosamunda/Desktop/coderhouse/fs/' }
```

I've tried to search for that ENOENT error, and what I do understand is that the error appears when the path is incorrect, but the path does exist. If I try to print **archivos**, it returns "**undefined**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ENOENT` means the path doesn't exist. It looks like you may be missing the `/` at the beginning of the path (to make it an absolute path).